# Examples of real stealth address from the blockchain

Tags: stealth-address

I am looking for examples of stealth addresses. Not only theoretically what they are, but real examples. What do they look like in the blockchain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one example: 47c99dab149170154cf1cdfb7e6a5993e1683e9d952aa0502b7b9f27f4129735

This is the public key for the first output in tx http://moneroblocks.info/tx/e706b52d74f74da37f0c016b976ede566fabf106c344a0fe1fb18cdb3751b0f6, the last tx made as of now.

I won't give the private key to it, both because I don't know it, and because it'd allow you to spend it :) But it'd look like a private key, which is, very much like the above (but modulo l).

Comment: To add, the [MoneroWorld explorer](http://Explore.MoneroWorld.com) allows you to search stealth addresses.

Answer (score 5):

Every single transaction uses stealth addresses. There's no way to opt-out of it. So you can just use any block explorer and view a Monero transaction, and you will see that the outputs don't go to the 95-character long Monero addresses (that start with a 4) but go to some random 64-character 'address'.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my testing code:
https://github.com/jackenbaer/monero/blob/main/test_monero_crypto.py